# Spring 3 , Spring Web Flow 2 dependencies problem

Tags: spring, maven-2, maven, spring-webflow

i am trying to use spring 3 with spring web flow 2
the problem is that i am using spring 3, and spring web flow 2 depends on spring 2 libraries so it tries to download them, so is the solution that in every web flow library i will exclude all spring 3 libraries or what ? please advise

here's my pom file:

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version> 
        <tiles.version>2.1.3</tiles.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- a collection of internal and external dependencies -->
    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
            <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        -->


        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

            <!-- Scope controls which dependencies are available in which classpath, and which dependencies are included with an application -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- End Of Spring Dependencies -->

        <!-- Container-provided dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Provides database connection pooling services 
        (technique used for sharing server resources among requesting clients) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- End Of Hibernate Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


      <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>8.1-407.jdbc3</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- WebFlow, JSF Dependencies -->

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.springframework.webflow</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.springframework.js</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.springframework.faces</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.springframework.binding</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.15</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.jboss.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
      </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Is it a requirement you use an old version of spring-webflow?

Comment: so if i use the latest version with spring 3 it will work fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used latest version of spring 3.0.5 and version 2.2.1 of webflow and exception was gone.